# Why is git not using identity set in ssh config file?

Tags: ssh, git, cygwin

I am trying to connect to my local [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) server. I have set it up to use the integrated SSH server on port 2222. I am running Windows. Gitea is running fine.

Now I want to connect using [Cygwin's git](https://cygwin.com/git.html). For testing the connection to my repository I am using the [ls-remote](https://superuser.com/a/833286/374087) command which works fine if I use the [`GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITSSHCOMMANDcode) option like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" git ls-remote --exit-code -h ssh://username@localhost:2222/username/Repo.git
```

Next I want to simplify life using `~/.ssh/config`:

```
host gitea
 HostName localhost
 Port 2222
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 User username
```

However, this does fail with error `Unable to open connection`:

```
git ls-remote --exit-code -h ssh://gitea/username/Repo.git
```

Problem: `IdentityFile` is not applied. This works:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" git ls-remote --exit-code -h ssh://gitea/username/Repo.git
```

I am certain though, that my `~/.ssh/config` is correct, because connecting via directly `ssh -vv gitea` works. Output (extract):

```
[...]
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
[...]
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:XXX /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:XXX
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:2222).
[...]
```

So why is `git` not using `IdentityFile` from `~/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh"` was enough. This means that `git` was using some other SSH client. Probably the one of OpenSSH which happened to be on the system path:

```
$ whereis ssh
ssh: /usr/bin/ssh.exe /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe /usr/share/man/man1/ssh.1.gz
```

I fixed the issue by adding `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="/usr/bin/ssh"` to `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This worked for me... I was using Window's Git command on my cygwin command line (as I checked what git it was using by trying 'which git') and realized maybe its not using the ssh command i want. just adding this GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh" env var worked for me